# Calling VBScript from JavaScript during window load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript

I am trying to print a web page silently using VBScript during page load from JavaScript but the function is not recognized in JavaScript.

```
<script language="VBScript">
    sub Print()
        OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
        OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
        OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
        call WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,1)
    End Sub

    document.write "<object id='WB' width='0' height='0' classid='CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'></object>"
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {          
        Print();
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me how to call this from jquery or javascript?

Comment: There is no such thing as "VB6 script" and what you have there is VBScript which is something entirely different from VB6 which isn't a scripting language.  Edit your tags to get more answers.